# Text on top of the arrows in GGDAG

Tags: r, ggplot2, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to plot a ggdag plot (Directed Acyclic Graphs in R) using the wonderful `ggdag` package in R (https://github.com/malcolmbarrett/ggdag). Here is an example script.

```
library(ggdag)
library(ggplot2)
example <- ggdag::dagify(d ~ p,m ~ d,y ~ d,y ~ m)
ggdag::ggdag(example)+theme_dag()
```

I was wondering if there is a way to add some text on top of the arrows so that the plot looks like

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option could be using `annotate`. Keep in mind that you need to use `set.seed`, because the dag will keep chaning from position randomly. You can use the following code:

```r
library(ggdag)
library(ggplot2)
example <- ggdag::dagify(d ~ p,m ~ d,y ~ d,y ~ m)
set.seed(1)
ggdag::ggdag(example)+theme_dag() +
  annotate("text", x = c(0.4, 0), , y = c(2.6, 2.3), , label = "beta==x p =xx")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Any thoughts on how to adjust `annotate` when you have 8 or 10 variables in a plot?

Comment: @DSTO, you could create two vectors for your x and y coordinates of your text!